# refreshing a View below onOpenURL

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

I'm making a chat-like application with a main view called `ChatView` and a list of `Conversation View`s with different contacts. The idea behind the app is that messages are split into 3 parts and  sent in a form of hyperlinks. The person receiving the message clicks the link and is presented with a sheet with a list of contacts in the app. When choosing a contact, the message is added to Core Data.
I registered an `onOpenURL` handler on `ChatView`:

```
            ChatView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.shared.container.viewContext)
                .onOpenURL { url in
                    acceptedURL = .init(id: .init(), url: url)
                }
                .sheet(item: $acceptedURL) { link in
                    MessageDecryptView(url: link.url)
                }
        }
```

Inside `MessageDecryptView` I do some processing and add the message to Core Data.

The issue I have is that if the app is displaying a conversation with specific user and a hyperlink is opened adding the message to that same conversation, the conversation is not updated when the sheet dismisses. Instead the user has to go back to `ChatView` and enter the `ConversationView` again which fetches the messages from Core Data `onAppear`.

So for the scenario of `MessageDecryptView` sheet being opened on top of `ConversationView` I am looking for one of two possible solutions:

1. how to go back to `ChatView`
2. (prererable) How to update the displayed `ConversationView` with a message that was just added

I would appreciate any help!

**EDIT**
My app is written in SwiftUI. I have ViewModel classes that are used by my views for interacting with Core Data. Inside `ConversationView` there is

```
@ObservedObject private var messageVM = MessageViewModel()
```

and then the following is how I fetch the data from the database:

```
.onAppear(perform: {
            userVM.getCurrentUser()
            messageVM.getConversation(with: user.id!)
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to notify your view(s) that something changed in the messages.
So just before - or inside of

```
 MessageDecryptView(url: link.url)
```

insert

```
MessagesClass.objectWillChange.send()
```

and replace `MessagesClass`with the name of your `NSManagedObject` class in CoreData that contains your messages – the one that is used to display the messages in the view.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am getting an error:
*Instance member 'objectWillChange' cannot be used on type 'Message'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?*
I edited my question with more details on my implementation, could you have a look now? thank you!

Comment: sorry, I was not precise, you have to call it on the value, not the class: try `messageVM.objectWillChange.send()`

Answer (score 0):

We don't use view model objects in SwiftUI, we use property wrappers that make the View data struct behave like an object. And the one for core data object is `@ObservedObject` so body is called when the object changes, so replace:

```
.onAppear(perform: {
            userVM.getCurrentUser()
            messageVM.getConversation(with: user.id!)
        })
```

with

```
@ObservedObject var user: User
```

and

```
ChatView(user: user)
```

Then for fetching we use `@FetchRequest` and body is called when any of the objects change or an object is inserted, moved or deleted. So in your case it would look something like this:

```
@FetchRequest var conversations: FetchedResults<Conversation>

    init(user: User) {
        let sortDescriptors = [SortDescriptor(\Conversation.timestamp, order: sortAscending ? .forward : .reverse)]
        _conversations = FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: sortDescriptors, predicate: NSPredicate(format: "user = %@", user), animation: .default)
```

Alternatively you can pass in a `FetchRequest` to your View init if that is simpler:

```
ConversationsView(conversations: FetchRequest(...
```

You can also make an extension on your entity types to return pre-configured `NSFetchRequest`s that can be used to easily create `FetchRequest` structs, e.g.

```
extension Item {
    static func myFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Item> {
        let fr = Self.fetchRequest()
        fr.propertiesToFetch = ["title"]
        fr.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.timestamp, ascending: true)]
        return fr
    }
}


@FetchRequest(
    fetchRequest: Item.myFetchRequest(),
    animation: .default)
private var items: FetchedResults<Item>
```